# Derivation of Schrodinger's wave equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, notation

To derive 
$$i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \psi = H \psi,$$
we start with
$$i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} |\alpha \rangle = H| \alpha \rangle$$
and then multiply by $\langle x|$ on the left. This leads to 
$$i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \langle x|\alpha\rangle=\langle x|H|\alpha\rangle.$$
My question is why we simply write the right-hand side as $H\langle x|\alpha\rangle$, when we know that $\langle x|$ is not an energy eigenbra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wave function of a state vector<sup>1</sup> $|\alpha\rangle$ in coordinate representation is, *by definition*,
$$\psi(x) = \langle x|\alpha\rangle.$$
Now $|\beta\rangle = H|\alpha\rangle$ is just another state vector. So we can define a coordinate wave function for it, too; call it $\phi(x) \equiv (H\psi)(x)$ because it represents the result of the operator $H$ acting on the state represented by the function $\psi(x)$ above:
$$(H\psi)(x) \equiv \phi(x) = \langle x|\beta\rangle \equiv \langle x|\big(H|\alpha\rangle\big) \equiv \langle x|H|\alpha\rangle.$$
To make the notation nicer and to confuse the uninitiated, instead of $(H\psi)(x)$ we usually write $H\psi(x)$, but it certainly doesn’t mean $\psi(x)$ multiplied by $H$ (a number multiplied by an operator): it’s the value of the wave function $H\psi$ (as defined above) evaluated at the point $x$. Drop the final $(x)$ everywhere (and also the implicit $t$ argument assumed in your question) to get the desired expression.

If you think there’s something wrong with these quantum people, consider an example from basic analysis: if $x = 0$ and $f(0) = 1$, then $f(x)$ is $1$, but $\frac d{dx}f(x)$ is not $\frac d{dx}1 \equiv 0$ but $\left(\frac d{dx}f\right)(x)\equiv f'(0)$. Denote $\frac d{dx}$ by $H$ for extra *déjà vu*.

<sup><sup>1</sup> I’m going to keep calling it $|\alpha\rangle$, although one usually uses $|\psi\rangle, |\phi\rangle, |\chi\rangle,\ldots$ for arbitrary states and $|a\rangle$ for an eigenvector of an operator $\hat a$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $a$, as depicted by the startling expression $\hat a|a\rangle = a|a\rangle$; the latter is what $|x\rangle$ means (there is an $\hat x$ operator), and normally your notation would lead people to assume there’s an $\hat\alpha$ operator too.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

$H \langle x | \alpha \rangle$ doesn't mean anything, because $H$ is an operator on Hilbert space while $\langle x | \alpha \rangle$ is just a number. What happens is that if $\psi(x) = \langle x | \alpha \rangle$, then $\langle x |H| \alpha \rangle = H\psi(x)$.

Sketch of proof: We know that $H$ is a function of $X$ and $P$ (I'll use uppercase for operators). It can be shown that

$$\langle x |X| \alpha \rangle = x\langle x | \alpha \rangle = x\psi$$

and

$$\langle x |P| \alpha \rangle = \frac1{i\hbar} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \langle x | \alpha \rangle = \frac1{i\hbar} \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}\ .$$

Then it's true that for any function $f$,

$$\langle x |f(X)| \alpha \rangle = f(x) \langle x | \alpha \rangle$$

and

$$\langle x |f(P)| \alpha \rangle = f(\frac1{i\hbar} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}) \langle x | \alpha \rangle\ ;$$

this can be shown by doing a power series expansion of $f$. Using the same method we get that

$$\langle x |H(X,P)| \alpha \rangle = H(x,\frac1{i\hbar}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}) \langle x | \alpha \rangle\ ,$$

which is precisely what $H\psi(x)$ means.

Comment: Thank you Javier, in the second line of your proof, how do you know how the ∂/∂x acts on ⟨x| ?

Comment: @NavidSanayei: the derivative doesn't act on $\langle x |$, it acts on $\langle x | \alpha \rangle$, which is a regular function of $x$. The proof that this is the position space representation of $P$ can be found in any QM book, or probably somewhere on the internet.